# Difference between fz, sz and f

Tags: dynamics, articulation, interpretation

What is exactly the difference between ***f*** (forte) and ***fz*** (forzato) ? I thought for long time that ***fz*** is similar to ***sf*** (sforzando), i.e. that it's a punctual dynamic that works only at the moment where it's written, but just after the ***fz*** we use the same nuance (for example, if we are in ***p***, then we want an accent at some point, and thus write ***fz***, but just after the accent, we go back to ***p***). However, I'm actually playing a piece where we are indeed in ***p***, at some point the composer wrote ***fz***, but in several interpretation I know, pianists stay in **f**. So, maybe ***sf*** and ***fz*** are quite different, and I was wondering if maybe ***fz*** could be ***sf*** +***f***. Could someone gives more details ?

Comment: In my experience, the most common abbreviation for _sforzando_ is not _sf_ but _sfz._  I would also note that, in Italian, _sforzando_ and _forzato_ both mean _forced._

Comment: Depends on who the composer was.

Comment: *sf* Is often glossed as *subito forte*

Comment: Note, this question mentions pianists but is not tagged with any particular instrument in mind. String and wind instruments are able to shape the "envelope" of the note to emphasize the attack or to sustain the emphasis for the duration of the note. (The answer to "what's the difference between an accent and sfz" is still "depends on the composer and the context," but for such instruments the difference one way or the other is often the relationship of the attack to the sustain.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that ***sf*** is often defined as ***subito forte*** rather than *sforzando*.

> *subito forte* / ***sf*** /  suddenly loud
> ...
> *sforzando* / ***sfz*** / with a sudden accent
> [C. Humphries and R. Goldsby *The Piano Handbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Piano_Handbook/w1srGMohAZoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=sf%20subito%20forte&pg=PA134&printsec=frontcover) (2002)

> ***sf*** / subito forte / suddenly loud  
> ***sfz*** / sforzando / suddenly loud
> [Matti Carter; *Pianist's Handbook*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Pianist_s_Handbook/Jl9-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=sf%20subito%20forte&pg=PA175&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

It begs the question if a single note (or passage) marked *sf* (suddenly loud) after a *piano* passage means  something different than an ordinary *f* after a *piano* passage if an accent isn't involved (i.e., *sfz*). Nonetheless, if I'm not mistaken, Schumann sometimes uses *sf* and *sfz* in the same piece.

Comment: I'm surprised by the suggestion that *sf* be taken for a *subito forte*. I would always assume it to be *sforzando*, and expect "*sub. f*" for subito forte. I would guess that such listings are descriptive rather than proscriptive?, and surely describe rarer usages.

Comment: I would potentially play piano followed by forte subito differently from piano followed by forte without “subito”. Specifically, with the subito there I interpret that I’m asked to not have any crescendo or interpretive dynamics leading up to the forte, and instead preserve and maybe enhance the dynamic contrast at the start of the f sub. section.

Answer (score 1):

From *The Oxford Companion to Music* (ed. Alison Latham, 2003):

> **forte** (It.). 'Strong', i.e., loud; it is abbreviated *f*.

> **forza** (It.). 'Force', 'strength'; *forzando*, *forzato*, 'forcing', 'forced', i.e., strongly accented.

> **sforzando, sforzato** (It.). 'Forcing', 'forced', i.e., accented. In the 19th century it was used to mark an accent within the prevailing dynamic, but it has now acquired the connotation of sudden loudness; it is abbreviated *sf* or *sfz*.